# Javascript save on click option

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

At default in catalog page there are 3 products per row (33,3333% flex-basis) and clicking on buttons it changes to 25% or 20% and that works fine. But when I'm going to next page (or reloading) the settings are not saved. How can I save them for users?

**I got a HTML code:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction1()">5 items</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">4 items</button>
<button onclick="myFunction3()">3 items</button>
```

**and javascript code**

```
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x, i;
    x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.flexBasis = "20%";
    }
  }

function myFunction2() {
  var x, i;
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.flexBasis = "25%";
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  var x, i;
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.flexBasis = "33.33333%";
  }
} 
</script>
```

Do I need to change already existing javascript/html or I can find the way how to make it work? (using localstorage)

Comment: You can store the widths in `localStorage`, and on page load get it and update based on the `localStorage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can call your function on load if your localstorage have something ... just checkout below code you find easy to unserstand

```
        window.onload = function() {
    let checkStorage = window.localStorage.getItem("myFunction")
    if(checkStorage == 1){
    myFunction();
    } 

     if(checkStorage == 2){
    myFunction2();
    } 
    if(checkStorage == 3){
    myFunction3();
    } 



    };

    // your function with localstorage

    function myFunction() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("myFunction" ,1)
    var x, i;
    x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.flexBasis = "20%";
    }
    }

    function myFunction2() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("myFunction" ,2)
    var x, i;
    x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.flexBasis = "25%";
    }
    }

    function myFunction3() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("myFunction" ,3)
    var x, i;
    x = document.querySelectorAll(".product-type-simple");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.flexBasis = "33.33333%";
    }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance. Your code works, but only 2 times. 

Default: 3 in a row

1.After pressing myFunction it shows 5 items even after reloading
2. Then after choosing 4 it also works fine
3. But when I tried to switch again to 5 or 3 it stopped working and was default option (33,3333%)

Comment: you need only one you mean? check now i have updated it

Comment: works pretty good. Thank you very much for assistance.

The 1 con is that when I go to next page product images loads for a second with 3 default images and then it automatically changes to 5 (flickering). But i will live with that :)

Thank you once again.

Comment: you can use use some preloader for that , it happens because window.onload occurs after your DOM loaded so your default style paint first then whatever in the scripts will run and css paint again , so that is what happening there and thats why people use "Shimmers" . if this answer solved your problem mark it as accepted for others

Answer (score 0):

## Session Storage

For that purpose I would guess you to use session storages.

Set data:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Get:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("key");
```

Remove:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Clear:

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

By the way: I would recommend you to use the `for(const obj of list)` to loop over lists.